# CSS - Zoom in background only (no overlay text)

Tags: css, background, bootstrap-4, zooming

I'm trying to do the background image zoom in effect. The code below represents one clickable element with an image background. The problem I have is that it zooms in everything in that div including child divs. I'd just want the background image to zoom in (leave the overlay text intact)

```
<a class="outer-tile tile-text" href="#">
    <div class="inner-tile d-flex flex-column align-items-start" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300')">
      <div class="mb-auto p-2">
        <span class="b-dark p-1">MyTag</span>
      </div>
      <div class="b-dark w-100 p-2">
        <h3>My Title</h3>
        <p>This is the content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>


.outer-tile {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 400px;
}

.inner-tile {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.inner-tile:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/m-herda/pen/pOapwy):

How would I make only the background to zoom in without zooming in on text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the background image on an element that is a sibling to the text elements, not a parent. Then use positioning and z-index to place it behind them:

```
.outer-tile {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 400px;
  position:relative;
}

.tile-underlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.outer-tile:hover .tile-underlay {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

  <a class="outer-tile tile-text" href="#">
      <div class="tile-underlay d-flex flex-column align-items-start" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300')"></div>
      <div class="mb-auto p-2">
        <span class="b-dark p-1">MyTag</span>
      </div>
      <div class="b-dark w-100 p-2">
        <h3>My Title</h3>
        <p>This is the content</p>
      </div>

  </a>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLyYKY